# Storm (v0.9.2-incubating) Supervisor starting error after I rebooted the machine

Tags: apache-storm

Recently I've deployed storm on a local virtual machine using VMWare. The version deployed is v0.9.2-incubating release version The issue I am facing is that '$ storm supervisor' does NOT work after EVERY SINGLE reboot.

Right now, the lousy fix I am using to clean up storm.local.dir directory. And I hope someoen can help me to get a novel solution for this.

```
Zookeeper version: zookeeper-3.4.6
Storm version: 0.9.2-incubating (uses Netty transport)
zeromq version: zeromq-4.0.5
jzmq version: jzmq-master (wget https://github.com/nathanmarz/jzmq/archive/master.zip)
Both Storm and Zookeeper run on the same machine.
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz
RAM: 1001.4 MiB
```

**The error Message I got after running '$ storm supervisor' is shown below:**

```
2014-11-10 12:09:56 b.s.event [ERROR] Error when processing event java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
    at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.deserialize(Utils.java:93) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    at backtype.storm.utils.LocalState.snapshot(LocalState.java:45) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    at backtype.storm.utils.LocalState.get(LocalState.java:56) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$sync_processes.invoke(supervisor.clj:207) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:619) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at clojure.core$partial$fn__4190.doInvoke(core.clj:2396) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at backtype.storm.event$event_manager$fn__2378.invoke(event.clj:39) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2323) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2792) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:800) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:298) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
    at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.deserialize(Utils.java:88) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
2014-11-10 12:09:56 b.s.event [ERROR] Error when processing event java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
    at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.deserialize(Utils.java:93) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    at backtype.storm.utils.LocalState.snapshot(LocalState.java:45) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    at backtype.storm.utils.LocalState.get(LocalState.java:56) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$mk_synchronize_supervisor$this__6330.invoke(supervisor.clj:307) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    at backtype.storm.event$event_manager$fn__2378.invoke(event.clj:39) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2323) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2792) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:800) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:298) ~[na:1.6.0_33]
    at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.deserialize(Utils.java:88) ~[storm-core-0.9.2-incubating.jar:0.9.2-incubating]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2):

I also ran through same problem. If you google a bit with the errors, you would find this [mail-archive](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/storm-user/201404.mbox/%3CE3ABC1ECEC0B0E40AF6D4B8ED111011E2334F72F@HDXDSP51.us.lmco.com%3E) . The solution according to this is:

1. Stop all the storm and zookeeper processes.
2. Then clear the storm and zookeeper data directories. You fixed your Storm data directory
   in your storm.yaml file and zookeeper data directory in your zoo.cfg or any file named
   by you.
3. Restart the processes.

   everything seemed fine.